# how to publish button click event using delegate command in prism

Tags: .net, wpf, prism

I have a Button in one `xaml` and `grid` in another `xaml` I want to populate values in grid when I click the button. How to do that using `Prism`.

```
 public class buttonloadviewmodel: NotificationObject
        {
            public DelegateCommand<object> combochange { get; set; }
            private readonly IEventAggregator eventaggs;
            public buttonloadviewmodel(IEventAggregator eventaggs)
            {
                this.eventaggs = eventaggs;
                InititializeDelegateCommand();
                                }
            private void InititializeDelegateCommand()
            {
                combochange = new DelegateCommand<object>(onselection, canexecute);
            }
                private bool canexecute(object arg)
            {
                return true;
            }

            private void onselection(object obj)
            {
                eventaggs.GetEvent<buttonclickaevent>().Publish(Button.ClickEvent);
            }
                List<string> usenamse = new List<string>();
            public List<string> useNamse
            {
                get { return usenamse; }
                set
                {
                    usenamse = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.useNamse);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: bind a command to the button, bind a collection to the grid, and fill the collection from the command's execution delegate...

Comment: Thanks sir But i'm new to wpf can u Give an example.

Comment: What have you got already? Put some code that's not working in the question, or it might be downvoted quickly, as stackoverflow isn't meant to be a code writing service...

Comment: Sir I Post The code. First i used Combo box where i'm able to fire an event.But I don't know how to do same when I  click button.

Comment: you bind the click of a button to the combochange-command by putting `Command="{Binding combochange}"` in the button's definition

Comment: Thanks Sir it Worked Perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the **Grid class** doesn't have an ItemsSource property so you can not binding the Items easily. I use instead of a Grid a DataGrid

### MainWindow.xaml

```
 <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel></local:ViewModel>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
         <StackPanel>
             <Button Command="{Binding AddCommand}">Add data</Button>
             <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
             </DataGrid>
         </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### ViewModel.cs

```
public class ViewModel
    {
        public DelegateCommand AddCommand { get; private set; }
        public ObservableCollection<String> Items{get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        public ViewModel()
        {
            AddCommand = new DelegateCommand(AddMethod);
        }

        private void AddMethod()
        {
            Items.Add("Hello");
        }
    }
```

I hope this small example can help you with Bindings and Commands.